# Проверка номеров телефона через api telegram

Tags: telegram

Пытаюсь реализовать проверку телефонных номеров на python, зарегистрированы ли они в базе телеграмма или нет. В документации написано:

> (auth.checkPhone "79123413132")

А куда и как отправлять запрос не ясно. Если можно ссылкой, через http, то было бы вообще шикарно.

Answer (score 1):

Делюсь тем, что удалось найти по вашему вопросу:

```
$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API();
if (isset($token)) { // Login as a bot
$MadelineProto->bot_login($token);
}
if (isset($number)) { // Login as a user
$sentCode = $MadelineProto->phone_login($number);
echo 'Enter the code you received: ';
$code = '';
for ($x = 0; $x < $sentCode['type']['length']; $x++) {
    $code .= fgetc(STDIN);
}
$MadelineProto->complete_phone_login($code);
}

$auth_CheckedPhone = $MadelineProto->auth->checkPhone(['phone_number' => string, ]);
```

Найдено на GitHub. Библиотека для ознакомления: **MadelineProto**. Вот [она](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) на GitHub'е

Comment: Стоит метка `Python`

Comment: @Alban Наглядно посмотреть на код, указанный мной в примере, можно сделать какие то выводы и понять как и что работает. Видел, что по `Python`

Comment: метка python не критична , любой код может помочь

Comment: @egorkh Вы ознакомились с примером? Получилось?

Comment: я голосую за , но честно говоря у меня где то косяк